# colorpicker in MVC-project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, color-picker

I got this textbox where i can put a hex-color to change the color in my application:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Page.Color)
```

Is there a, not to complicated, way to change the textbox into
a colorpicker?

For simplicity i try to add farbtastic to the layout, here is the full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/farbtastic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/farbtastic.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#demo').hide();
        $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo" style="color: red; font-size: 1.4em">jQuery.js is not present. You must install jQuery in this folder for the demo to work.</div>

    <form action="" style="width: 400px;">
        <div class="form-item"><label for="color">Color:</label><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></div><div id="picker"></div>
    </form>




    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The `<div id="demo" style="color: red; font-size: 1.4em">jQuery.js is not present. You must install jQuery in this folder for the demo to work.</div>` 
Does not run so I suppose it works...However, no wheel is showing in my view, just the
iputboxes. What could be wrong?

Comment: this might point you in the right direction http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Farbtastic](http://acko.net/files/farbtastic/farbtastic12.zip)

Include farbtastic.js and farbtastic.css into your solution. Then have this html and jquery on page -

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Farbtastic</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="farbtastic.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="farbtastic.css" type="text/css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').hide();
    $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');
  });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery Color Picker: Farbtastic</h1>

<div id="demo" style="color: red; font-size: 1.4em">jQuery.js is not present. You must install jQuery in this folder for the demo to work.</div>

<form action="" style="width: 400px;">
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color">Color:</label><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></div><div id="picker"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then when you run -

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One question though, lets say i have several different textboxes where I put differen colors for different things. Is is possible to use the same "color-wheel" for them all?
If I could put the pointer in one textbox and then click the wheel it would be great.

Comment: @user2915962 You should be able to use one Picker for multiple textboxes.